# Actualizar layout de Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, djangorestframework, vuetify

Existe alguna manera de pasar o actualizar información desde un page de Nuxt al layout que el page está utilizando?

Debo actualizar el v-text de `<v-toolbar-title v-text="header" />` en el layout dinámicamente con elementos del page que está utilizando el layout.

Espero haberme explicado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas, recomiendo usar la [store](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/)

En Store: guardas la variable

```
state: () => ({
  tuVariable: 'inicial'
}),
```

En layout: consumes la variable con una `computed property`

```
computed: {
  porConsumirVar () {
    return this.$store.state.tuVariable
  }
```

En cualquier página / componente: modificas la variable

```
this.$store.commit('tuVariable/add', 'modificado')
```